# MVC4 How to ignore validation when form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC validation. I was trying to ignore the validation when I change the index in dropdownlist with submit form. However, if I have another submit button in the from fired the validation, the method below would not work.

dropdown list :

```
    $("#dropdown").change(function () {

        $('#MyForm').validate().cancelSubmit = true;
        $('#MyForm').submit();
    });
```

another button:

```
    $("#Button").click(function () {
      $('#MyForm').removeData('validator');
      $('#MyForm').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#MyForm'));
      $('#MyForm').submit();
    });
```

Because I have some of html elements are dynamically genrated by ajax call, and I want to validate those dynamic elements also, when I hit submit. This is why I am doing this:

```
      $('#MyForm').removeData('validator');
      $('#MyForm').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#MyForm'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I did something below, I solved the issue.

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    $('#MyForm').removeData('validator');
    $('#MyForm').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $('#MyForm').validate().cancelSubmit = true;
    $('#MyForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    { HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;}
}
```

or

```
$('input, textarea, select', 'form').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('data-val', 'false');
});
```

Comment: If I did this, all validations in the form would be disabled. At the moment, I just want to disable the validation when I change the index of this special dropdownlist. Other buttons or dropdownlist or links can still fire validation.

Comment: `$('input, textarea, select', 'form').each...` put this inside function and while index of your special dropdownlist changed call method and disable validation and simply when index changed again re-enable validation by calling another function. inside function change data-val value to true (`$(this).attr('data-val', 'true')`);

Answer (score 0):

You can also add special attribute to form submit button:

```
<button type="submit" formnovalidate>
```